# Task not serializable issue at window rank function in scala spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive

When i run my code from prod, Am not getting any task not serializable issue while when am trying to call from unit test case. am getting task not serializable from below code. Not getting what is the issue and why this strange behavior. Can anyone help on that or any better serialazable solution to get latest row from hive table ?

```
   val distinctBy = Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy(desc("updated_at"));
    val uniqueSellerDf = enrichedDf.withColumn("rank", rank().over(distinctBy))//row_number().over(distinctBy))     ### both rank function and row_number function have the same issue
      .where($"rank" === 1).drop("rank")

uniqueSellerDf.show()   //#### Getting task not serializable issue from show action cmd
```

Answer (score 0):

Do like this:

```
@transient val distinctBy = Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy(desc("updated_at"))
```

It's a long story. See [Task not serializable exception while running apache spark job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25914057/task-not-serializable-exception-while-running-apache-spark-job/43015968#43015968)  and https://medium.com/swlh/spark-serialization-errors-e0eebcf0f6e6 and https://nathankleyn.com/2017/12/29/using-transient-and-lazy-vals-to-avoid-spark-serialisation-issues/

Comment: Earlier I tried @transient also but no luck  cc : thebluephantom

Comment: Works for me. Interesting.

Comment: May be someting upstream. Need to show all code.